# Redirect user to login page after verification email is send to user using mail trap

Tags: laravel, email, verification

I'm trying to redirect users to the login page after email verification is sen. I'm using mail trap to send emails and secondly I do not want users to directly login after they verify the email.

Answer (score 0):

after verifying the email get user id and use loginUsingID method for user and then you can redirect user.

Answer (score 0):

after you verify the email on the controller just use redirect route to redirect user to the login page. Donot forget to logout all sessions as someone might have already been logged in before.

```
Auth::logout();
return redirect('login')->with('success', 'Account activated! Please log in.');
```